# Import specific columns from another Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

I used this query after studying from Google:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Mh5lEqBh1OBzuW5U1Fvr1MK_6doIvKmV23YKp4Fu0c/edit#gid=529591601","'iOS'!E:G"), "Select Col4",1)
```

I am getting the error as follows:

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col4
```

What should I do for it?

Comment: I'm wondering if the formula has a typographical error or if there is a conceptual error.

Answer (score 1):

User started by posting the above as an answer, so I presume is not going to return. The solution may be to change the `E:G` to `E:H`. Fortunately Google can count and isn't going to return the fourth column of **three**, as clearly stated in the error message:

> NO_COLUMN: Col4

Comment: The first line make this answer to look as "a commentary to another post", by the other hand the third statement looks confusing, isn't it?

Comment: IMHO that is the second statement. I was referring to "Fortunately Google can count and isn't going to..."